# How to insert a tab character in sublime text?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-3

I am trying to insert a tab into a document in Sublime Text.  I am using tabs for indentation.  Usually, I can insert a tab by pressing <kbd>→ Tab</kbd>.  However, sometimes instead of inserting a tab character, this performs a word completion.

It's hard to predict when this will happen, but when I notice it, I then press <kbd>Backspace</kbd>                <kbd>→ Tab</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd>

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 14):

Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> *doesn't* insert a literal tab for me in Sublime Text 3.

The only way for me to insert a literal tab is doing the following things:

- First, I *disable* the **`Indent Using Spaces`** option via menu **`View`** → **`Indentation`**.
- Then, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to insert a literal tab.

After you're done, switch back the option.

You can also click on the cell of the status bar which says **`Spaces: n`** or **`Tab Size: n`**, and switch the **`Indent Using Spaces`** option there.

Comment: Another trick I read about [in the Sublime Text forum](http://forum.sublimetext.com/t/insert-tab-characters-but-indent-using-spaces/9043) is to insert a character that you know isn't used anywhere in your code (the example given was a backtick, but you could paste a unicode character or something). Then invoke Search/Replace, ensure Regex is enabled, find your character and replace it with `\t`, which will result in a tab. It isn't super convenient for a one-off (though, neither is toggling the menu option) but works well if you know you're going to be inserting several tab characters.

Answer (score 11):

Do you find the word completion feature helpful? If not then turn it off and I'm sure that will fix your problem.

Alternatively if you press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> then that will insert a literal tab.

Or you can disable tab completion by adding this line to Preferences/File Settings - User:

```
"tab_completion": false
```

[Source](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/tab_completion.html)

Comment: Pressing `Shift` + `Tab` doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a tab in search/replace, just type a tab on a new line ("Indent using spaces" disabled), select and cut and then paste into either search or replace field.

Thought I'd add this in case anyone found this question like me searching for this option.